# What makes an object 0.5th generation?

Tags: heavy-object

In the third arc ("The Ant and the Grasshopper"), the enemy object is described as being "0.5th-generation".

What does that even mean? I thought that the very first object to be built was itself already considered 1st-generation. Is a 0.5th-generation object some sort of subpar imitation or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it's a [Generation 0.5](http://heavyobject.wikia.com/wiki/Generation_0.5) due to the fact it was not properly built, as the level of technology of its country was too low.

> The technology level of the Oceanian military nation is not high enough to actually build a proper Object, thus the codename of Generation 0.5.

It contains several cheap measures in order to keep it even stable enough to move.

> A single main gun is attached to the left side of the sphere. It's a few dozen meters long and reinforced with numerous steel bridge-like wires. It would likely have been fine without them, but there is a risk of the gun damaging itself with its own weight while it's held horizontal for long periods of time. It's a cheap countermeasure that would never have even been considered for a normal Object.

Therefore, since it is a downgraded version of a normal object and built with improper technology, it is called a Generation 0.5.

> The prologue and afterword confirm that the Generation 0.5 was a degraded version of the Information Alliance's [Gatling 033](http://heavyobject.wikia.com/wiki/Gatling_033). The technology and design were given to the Oceanian military nation by the MIB.